# Which IP as dns server for vmware nat config?

Tags: networking, dns, vmware, nat

Unfortunately I don't seem to understand how NAT on vmware works, so I'll start by describing my setup:

Vmware guest with a linux system, ie fedora.
It has a static ip configured from the NAT ip range (ie 192.168.72.132) from VMNet 8.

The gateway according to vmware is 192.168.72.2 and my host network has 192.168.178.1 as ip from that range.

I would like to have all dns requests be resolved by the DNS port my "real" host machine uses. The host gets the ip from the company's dhcp server and can therefore resolv some domains that are not public.

From what I understand, I would therefor set the nat gateway ip as dns1 and that is what I did.

But when I run the nslookup I can see the following:

```
IPADDR=192.168.72.132                                                                                                                                                                                         
PREFIX=32
GATEWAY=192.168.72.2
DNS1=192.168.178.2
DNS2=8.8.8.8
...
$ nslookup superuser.com
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   superuser.com
Address: 151.101.1.69
```

So it seems that it's not working with that configuration.

What is it I am doing wrong?